ubuntu 24 does not detect 5ghz networks
Ubuntu 24 does not detect 5GHz networks. It detects the 2.4GHz ones without problems, but I have two 5GHz ones and it does not detect any. The same computer with Windows 11 detects them without problems. I have another computer with another version of Ubuntu (the one with the jellyfish) and it detects the 5GHz ones without problems.
